# Generating number strings of a given length and base using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've been trying to tweak below script to generate all the number strings of a given size and base. It seems the function is returning to an incorrect `str` value... Any help ?
(Below script is supposed to print all binary strings of length 4, starting from `0000` to `1111`)
(I am using `str.replace` to replace the last digit of `str` before calling the function)

```js
function generateStringsOfLength(size, base, str) {
  if (str.length >= size) {
    document.write(str + "<br>");
    return;
  }
  //outer loop to change position value
  for (let pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
    //appending an empty char to the "str", this empty char will be replaced by "val" in each iteration of the below inner loop
    str += " ";
    //inner loop change only the lsb digit from "0" to "base-1" 
    for (let val = 0; val < base; val++) {
      str = str.replace(/.$/, val);
      generateStringsOfLength(size, base, str);
    }
  }
}
generateStringsOfLength(4, 2,"");
```

EDIT :
Actually I was trying to generalize and implement below pseudocode for binary strings :

```
generateBinary(length, string)    
if(length > 0)
    generateBinary(length-1, string + "0")
    generateBinary(length-1, string + "1")
else
    print(string)
```

The only modification I did in my code was to use a loop for calling the function recursively "base" times...

Comment: Why so complicated? `for (var i=0; i<n; i++) console.log(i.toString(base).padStart(size, "0"))`

Comment: What good is that `for (let pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {` loop? (Omit it and it should work.) Can you explain your train of thought, how you designed the recursion to work?

Comment: @Bergi sorry my intention was to learn recursion better, so I've been rewriting some scripts using recursion... just for fun.. thank you :)

Comment: @Bergi I'll quickly comment the code and mention you. I really appreciate you helping me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bergi I've commented the code. Kindly have a look. I'm going to try removing the `for (let pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {` loop and and see what happens..

Comment: Yes, you've described what the code does, but *why* did you write the code to do that? Especially, what did you expect the recursive call to do? What is your base case, and what is your reduction?

Comment: @Bergi I'll explain it in the post itself and mention you again :)

Comment: @Bergi I've attached in the post  my starting pseudocode I was using to implement...

Comment: @Bergi here is the jsfiddle for that pseudocode which works for only binary strings
https://jsfiddle.net/ganeshie8/zt9ey4qa/

Comment: My bad! @Bergi I see now why you asked why that initial `for` loop was needed. It is not needed. Looks I've figured out my mistake... I think I can take it from here. If you had time and posted your first comment as answer, I'd love to mark it best :)

Comment: Yes, that fiddle shows the right approach. You only need to change the `3` to `base` :-) I don't think I need to post an answer anymore, @trincot already did it. Glad to have helped you arriving at the solution on your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that your outer loop is making `str` longer. But it should not be there: the string is *already* made longer in the recursive call. That outer loop should be removed.

Secondly, the way you change a digit with a regular expression is not very efficient. Instead, just use the argument to pass the string concatenated with the additional digit, without changing the value of `str` in the current context:

Finally, don't use `document.write`: it is really bad practice. Instead use `console.log`, or even better, don't output anything in the function itself. It is better to let the function return the result as an array of strings, and let the caller decide what to do with it:

```js
function generateStringsOfLength(size, base, str) {
    if (str.length >= size) {
        return [str]; // Don't output. Instead build an array with strings
    }
    const result = [];
    for (let val = 0; val < base; val++) {
        // Don't change str. Instead pass the modified value on-the-fly
        // Collect the result in a growing array
        result.push(...generateStringsOfLength(size, base, str + val));
    }
    return result; // Return the collected strings
}

const result = generateStringsOfLength(4, 2,"");
console.log(result);
```

I suppose you are playing around with recursion, because the result is much easier to produce like this:

```js
function generateStringsOfLength(size, base, str) {
    return Array.from({length: base ** size}, 
                      (_, i) => i.toString(base).padStart(size, '0'));
}

const result = generateStringsOfLength(4, 2,"");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ahh looks elegant. Now after seeing your code, I've no idea how I had put that outer `for` loop that kept me confused. What must I do to get a fraction of your awesomeness in programming?:) Thank you so much!